# Start and stop service use a checkbox

Tags: android, android-service

I have two questions..

**1.** I have developed an Android application and I have: 
Activity A
Activity B
in Activity B I have 4 togglebuttons. If I click in ToggleButton1, I run a service in background.
(If togglebutton1 is on run my service)
but if the service is running and I return in activity A and later open Activity B, the togglebutton1 is off but the service is still running .... why?

**2.** I want to run more than a service but how to kill a service using an ID or something?

This is my code - Class Services:

```
 @Override
   public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this,"Service created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intenc, int flags, int idArranque) {

       new FTask().execute();

       return START_STICKY;
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {

       Toast.makeText(this,"Service stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intencion) {

       return null;
   }
```

and here there are the togglebuttons:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(btnAtterraDecolla.isChecked()){

                Intent i = new Intent(DettagliVolo.this, MyAct.class);

                startService(i);

            }else{

                stopService(new Intent(DettagliVolo.this,MyAct.class));
            }
         }
    });
....more togglebuttons similar
```

This is a ToggleButton

Thank you in advance!

EDITED:

```
        btnAtterraDecolla.setChecked(
            getSharedPreferences("btnAtterraDecolla", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getBoolean("state", false)
    );

    btnAtterraDecolla.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if(isChecked){

                Intent i = new Intent(DettagliVolo.this, RunAsyncTask.class);


                i.putExtra("AoP", AoP);                 

                pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DettagliVolo.this, 0, i, 0);
                alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pintent);


            }else{

                alarm.cancel(pintent);
                stopService(new Intent(DettagliVolo.this,RunAsyncTask.class));

            }
            getSharedPreferences("btnAtterraDecolla", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit().putBoolean("state", isChecked)
            .commit();
        } 
    });
```

LOGCAT: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7589070/
crash here:

```
                    alarm.cancel(pintent);
```

RE-EDIT:

```
public class DettagliVolo extends Activity {

boolean AoP;

AlarmManager alarm;
PendingIntent pintent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dettaglivolo);

    Intent intent = getIntent();


    this.AoP = intent.getBooleanExtra("AoP", true );

    TextView AtterraDecolla = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);


    final ToggleButton btnAtterraDecolla = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);


    btnAtterraDecolla.setChecked(
            getSharedPreferences("btnAtterraDecolla", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getBoolean("state", false)
    );

    btnAtterraDecolla.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(DettagliVolo.this, RunAsyncTask.class);
            pintent = PendingIntent.getService(DettagliVolo.this, 0, i, 0);
            alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            if(isChecked){


                i.putExtra("AoP", AoP);                 

                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pintent);

            }else{

                alarm.cancel(pintent);
                stopService(new Intent(DettagliVolo.this,RunAsyncTask.class));

            }
            getSharedPreferences("btnAtterraDecolla", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit().putBoolean("state", isChecked)
            .commit();
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting and stopping two different services

```
new Intent(DettagliVolo.this, MyAct.class);
new Intent(DettagliVolo.this,FlightService.class);
```

**EDIT** after question update

When you open start a new activity, the layout is drawn. To put it straight, any event that triggers `onCreate` forces the layout to be drawn. It is up to you to keep the state of the toggle button. I'll advise you use `SharedPreferences`, how?

On the very first launch of the activity, we assume the service isn't started and a click on the checkbox should trigger a start of the service.

- Use `OnCheckedChangeListener( ... )` instead of `OnClickListener`, it's more appropriate semantically.
- In the `onCreate` method of activity B after inflating the layout, check for the state of this toggle button.

.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ToggleButton toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    toggleButton1.setChecked(
            getSharedPreferences("TOGGLE_BUTTON_1", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getBoolean("state", false)
    );

    toggleButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked)
                startService(null);
            else
                stopService(null);

            getSharedPreferences("TOGGLE_BUTTON_1", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .edit().putBoolean("state", isChecked)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry i have wrong.. updates 1st post.
Can you help me?

Comment: I run AsyncTask into a Service for parse a webpage. I want stop this Service until the AsyncTask send a event. Sorry for my english

Comment: Yes can I stop a service know idArranque? ID service?

Comment: Hi i have a problem with your code... EDITED 1st post

Comment: I have tried but doesn't work. Can you make an example? thank you! EDited 1st post